# Google App Script - Error when Mapping - TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, mapping, google-sheets-api

With the guidance of the community I've recently learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198587/invalid-json-payload-with-sheets-spreadsheets-batchupdate/64207372?noredirect=1#comment113915205_64207372) about BatchUpdating background colors of a given google sheet.

I've attempted to apply this to my actual sheet but run into the error code. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

The code in my test sheet which works without issue is here:

```
var TestArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get("1eAq-RbtrCSMRPZ0p7XIpG3vd29yL-3SQ3D3JGyiUhKg", {
   ranges:"TestBackgroundSheet!A1:AD39", fields:"sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat.backgroundColor))))"
 });
 
 var backgroundColors = TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"]
                      .map(row => row["values"]
                      .map(value => value["effectiveFormat"]["backgroundColor"]));
```

I then copied and pasted this code into my actual project. In an attempt to troubleshoot I even copied the exact Sheet from my test project into the actual project. The code is listed here:

```
var TestArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get("1pcIKNUFmkk0d-UGg1sXl5xbsJC2WhocIHpM3et-CMgo", {
   ranges:"TestBackgroundSheet!A1:AD39", fields:"sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat.backgroundColor))))"
 });
 
 var backgroundColors = TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"]
                      .map(row => row["values"]
                      .map(value => value["effectiveFormat"]["backgroundColor"]));
```

As you can see the code is exactly the same except for a different SheetID. Despite this i continue to get the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` Error.

The error code references line 172 which is `.map(value => value["effectiveFormat"]["backgroundColor"]));`

Edit:
[image: Screenshot of Sheet]

Edit #2:

With inclusion of Rafa's Code I get this error code -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1 (line 177, file "macros")

Included code is below.

```
var TestArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get("1pcIKNUFmkk0d-UGg1sXl5xbsJC2WhocIHpM3et-CMgo", {
      ranges:"TestBackgroundSheet!A1:AD39",
      fields:"sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat.backgroundColor))))"
    });
     
    var rowData = TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"]
    .map(row => row.getValues()).toString()
    
    var backgroundColors = JSON.parse("[" + rowData + "]")
    .map(value => {
         let v = value["effectiveFormat"]
         return v ? v["backgroundColor"] : null
         })
```

Edit #3:

Logger of RowData with below code

```
for (var x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
      Logger.log(x + JSON.stringify(TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"][x]));
    }
```

I can see the issue is in the first four lines of Logger statements. While the empty rows in the "Testing Sheet" returns full rows of White background color (RGB {"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}) In the "Reat Sheet" I get an empty object for 3 of the first 4 lines.  I've include the first four lines out output below. I'm not sure why this occurs.

Actual:

```
[20-10-21 08:53:23:591 EDT] 0{}
[20-10-21 08:53:23:593 EDT] 1{"values":[{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}}]}
[20-10-21 08:53:23:595 EDT] 2{}
[20-10-21 08:53:23:597 EDT] 3{}
[20-10-21 08:53:23:600 EDT] 4{"values":[{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}}]}
```

Testing:

```
[20-10-21 05:53:14:167 PDT] 0{"values":[{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}}]}
[20-10-21 05:53:14:170 PDT] 1{"values":[{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}}]}
[20-10-21 05:53:14:193 PDT] 2{"values":[{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}}]}
[20-10-21 05:53:14:195 PDT] 3{"values":[{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}}]}
[20-10-21 05:53:14:198 PDT] 4{"values":[{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}}]}
```

Comment: `TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]` doesn't have `rowData`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't fully understand. How would it not have rowData? I'm running the function on an exact copy of a sheet that's in a different spreadsheet. The "Test" version much have rowData because it work. The "Actual" version doesn't? Is there a command to prove whats in that Array?

Comment: When the sheet has no values and the default background color of all cells, your request returns `{"sheets":[{"data":[{}]}]}`. In this case, `rowData` is not included. I think that by this, such error occurs. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation of `In an attempt to troubleshoot I even copied the exact Sheet from my test project into the actual project.`, can you provide the image of the sheet `TestBackgroundSheet!A1:AD39` in Spreadsheet `1pcIKNUFmkk0d-UGg1sXl5xbsJC2WhocIHpM3et-CMgo`?

Comment: @Tanaike - Thank you for the reply. I've edited my original question and included the requested screenshot. It is edited minimally because everything that is and "F" were names that I felt uncomfortable posting. Please let me know if there is anything else I can provide.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. When the sheet of `TestBackgroundSheet!A1:AD39` on the Spreadsheet of `1pcIKNUFmkk0d-UGg1sXl5xbsJC2WhocIHpM3et-CMgo` is the additional image, `rowData` is included in the returned values and no error occurs at the script. So unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: Try the api explorer or Log `console.log(JSON.stringify(TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Not all elements of `row["values"]` have data - and so you can't run `.map(value => value["effectiveFormat"]["backgroundColor"])` when that row doesn't have data.*

#### More Information:

You've got your data from the API using

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.get("1eAq-RbtrCSMRPZ0p7XIpG3vd29yL-3SQ3D3JGyiUhKg")
```

and filtered it accordingly with your field mask. The data you get as a response will be *everything* in the sheet - even the cells that do not have data for background colour. As a result of this, you can not map each row like this, as you will try and reference the `effectiveFormat` element where it simply doesn't exist.

#### Fix:

You can use the ternary operator to solve this; if the element `value["effectiveFormat"]` doesn't exist you can simply return `null`:

```
var rowData = TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"]
    .map(row => row.getValues()).toString()

var backgroundColors = JSON.parse("[" + rowData + "]")
    .map(value => {
        let v = value["effectiveFormat"]
        return v ? v["backgroundColor"] : null
    })
```

**NB:** The API also returns functions within the JSON objects in the response which you can use in Apps Script. This comes in handy because referencing `row["values"]` directly can return the object rather than the data:

```
console.log(TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"]
            .map(row => row["values"]))
```

yields:

```
[ 
  { 
    setPivotTable: [Function],
    getDataSourceTable: [Function],
    getDataValidation: [Function],
    getEffectiveValue: [Function],
    setNote: [Function],
    setFormattedValue: [Function],
    getTextFormatRuns: [Function],
    setUserEnteredFormat: [Function],
    toString: [Function],
    getFormattedValue: [Function],
    setEffectiveFormat: [Function],
    effectiveFormat: [Object],
    setDataSourceFormula: [Function],
    getPivotTable: [Function],
    setUserEnteredValue: [Function],
    setDataValidation: [Function],
    setDataSourceTable: [Function],
    getUserEnteredFormat: [Function],
    setEffectiveValue: [Function],
    getEffectiveFormat: [Function],
    getHyperlink: [Function],
    getNote: [Function],
    setHyperlink: [Function],
    getUserEnteredValue: [Function],
    setTextFormatRuns: [Function],
    getDataSourceFormula: [Function] 
  },
  ...
]
```

The `toString()` call after the first `.map(row => row.getValues())` gets past this before putting the data back into the second mapping function.

#### References:

- [Conditional (ternary) operator - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: thank you for the response. I will do a lot of testing and reading about your response today. In my first read of your response I didn't see why this would work in my test instance but not the real one despite the spreadsheet being the same?

Comment: Without seeing both spreadsheets it's impossible to say, though suffice to say they can't be identical if the code works on one but not the other. Likely some hidden setting or structure diff

Comment: Hmmm, ok. I'm not sure where to start looking for that difference. I've literally used google sheets built in "Copy To" -> "Existing Spreadsheet" Function. It should be identical...

Comment: I've updated my original Question to include an Edit that incorporates your suggested code in your Answer. Doing this i get the error -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1. This occurs at line -> var backgroundColors = JSON.parse("[" + rowData + "]")

Comment: Can you log `rowData` and paste its structural output here?

Comment: I believe I've done as you asked and added it as Edit #3 in the original Question.

Comment: I don't see an `Edit #3`.

Comment: I apologize. I attempted to post both these items at the same time and then was called away while posting the second edit. It's posted now and I've shown the difference between the two. Not sure why this difference is occurring. Thanks again for the guidance.

Comment: Glad to help! It looks like however you're defining `rowData` means that it's picking up different data for each sheet. Without looking at them it is impossible to say why, but also this is beyond the scope of your orignial question. I think that it would be best to pose this as a new question dedicated to the issue as it's beyond what this question was originally asking (map being undefined was because of empty rows being picked up, not *why* there are empty rows)

Comment: Your point about starting a new question regarding "why" is more than fair. Your initial answer suggested a fix for dealing with the empty rows and null value using the ternary operator. When implementing it I'm still getting the error code `SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1` as described in edit #2 of the original question. Any suggestions there?

Comment: Edit #2, `SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1` is a different error to the original question `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` and came about after the original error was rectified. You error is suggesting that `rowData` starts with a `,`, hence the string `"[" + rowData + "]"` has a `,` at position 1.