# Google App Script - SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1 - When Mapping Background Color Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, mapping, google-sheets-api

I've been attempting to BatchUpdate background colors back to a spreadsheet. The community was helping me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64432995/google-app-script-error-when-mapping-typeerror-cannot-read-property-map-o/64441618?noredirect=1#comment113993067_64441618). Ultimately, I ran into an error and it was suggested I post as a new question.

Current Code:

```
var TestArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get("1pcIKNUFmkk0d-UGg1sXl5xbsJC2WhocIHpM3et-CMgo", {
      ranges:"TestBackgroundSheet!A1:AD39",
      fields:"sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat.backgroundColor))))"
    });
    
    for (var x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
      Logger.log(x + JSON.stringify(TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"][x]));
    }
     
    var rowData = TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"]
    .map(row => row.getValues()).toString()
    
    var backgroundColors = JSON.parse("[" + rowData + "]")
    .map(value => {
         let v = value["effectiveFormat"]
         return v ? v["backgroundColor"] : null
         })
```

This returns an error as follows `SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1 (line 184, file "macros")`. Where line 184 is `var backgroundColors = JSON.parse("[" + rowData + "]")`. The first few lines of the Logger Statement results are posted below:

```
0{}
[20-10-21 18:05:08:257 PDT] 1{"values":[{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}}]}
[20-10-21 18:05:08:260 PDT] 2{}
[20-10-21 18:05:08:262 PDT] 3{}
[20-10-21 18:05:08:265 PDT] 4{"values":[{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"blue":1,"green":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"green":1,"red":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"red":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"green":1,"blue":1,"red":1}}},{},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}},{"effectiveFormat":{"backgroundColor":{"red":1,"green":1,"blue":1}}}]}
```

As I see it the first line of the code is null and I'm not sure why it suggests there is an unexpected "," in position 1. Suggestions on how to map this correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Edit #1:

My overall goal is to pull an array of a full sheets backgroundcolors then make adjustments to that array and then batchupdate it back to the same sheet. With guidance from from the community I had a simplified but functional version of this. This code is below.

```
function myFunction() {

var TestArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get("1eAq-RbtrCSMRPZ0p7XIpG3vd29yL-3SQ3D3JGyiUhKg", {
   ranges:"Awesome!A1:C3",
   fields:"sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat.backgroundColor))))"
 });
 
 var backgroundColors = TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"]
                      .map(row => row["values"]
                      .map(value => value["effectiveFormat"]["backgroundColor"]));
 
 var TotalText = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get("1eAq-RbtrCSMRPZ0p7XIpG3vd29yL-3SQ3D3JGyiUhKg", "Awesome!A1:C3").values; 
 
//Map Background Colors
var colorrows = backgroundColors.map(rowColors => {
 return {
   values: rowColors.map(cellColor => {
     return {
       userEnteredFormat: {
         backgroundColor: cellColor        
       }       
     }             
   })
 }
})

var spreadsheetId = "1eAq-RbtrCSMRPZ0p7XIpG3vd29yL-3SQ3D3JGyiUhKg";
var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
  requests: [{
    updateCells: {
      rows: colorrows,
      fields: 'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor',
      start: {
        sheetId: 1616717220,
        rowIndex: 0,
        columnIndex: 0
      }
    }
  }]
}, spreadsheetId)
}
```

Now when I attempted to use this code in a more complex spreadsheet I ran into a number of errors (often because of empty cells) which brought me to the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1 (line 184, file "macros")` from this question.

You've now fixed that error (which I greatly appreciate) and left me with an array with output.

```
[
  {"rowNumber":1,"columnNumber":1,"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}},
  ,
  ,
  ,
]
```

The Original simplified but functional Test sheet would output an array that would be fed into batchupdate code. The format from this function is below.

```
[20-10-23 11:32:04:093 EDT] {values=[{userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={red=1.0}}}, {userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={green=1.0, red=1.0, blue=1.0}}}, {userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={red=1.0, blue=1.0, green=1.0}}}]}
[20-10-23 11:32:04:098 EDT] {values=[{userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={red=1.0, blue=1.0, green=1.0}}}, {userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={green=1.0, red=1.0}}}, {userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={green=1.0, blue=1.0, red=1.0}}}]}
[20-10-23 11:32:04:102 EDT] {values=[{userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={blue=1.0, green=1.0, red=1.0}}}, {userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={red=1.0, blue=1.0, green=1.0}}}, {userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={red=0.2901961, green=0.5254902, blue=0.9098039}}}]}
```

I wondered if the output from your code -> `{"rowNumber":1,"columnNumber":1,"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}},` needs to be converted into the format -> `{values=[{userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={blue=1.0, green=1.0, red=1.0}}}` before it's put back into this code.

```
var spreadsheetId = "1eAq-RbtrCSMRPZ0p7XIpG3vd29yL-3SQ3D3JGyiUhKg";
var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
  requests: [{
    updateCells: {
      rows: colorrows,
      fields: 'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor',
      start: {
        sheetId: 1616717220,
        rowIndex: 0,
        columnIndex: 0
      }
    }
  }]
}, spreadsheetId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer for question 1:

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that it is required to check whether there is the property of `values` in the array of `rowData`, and also, whether there is the property of `effectiveFormat` in the array of `values`.

  - I think that this is the reason of your error.

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var TestArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get("1pcIKNUFmkk0d-UGg1sXl5xbsJC2WhocIHpM3et-CMgo", {
  ranges:"TestBackgroundSheet!A1:AD39",
  fields:"sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat.backgroundColor))))"
});

//  for (var x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
//    Logger.log(x + JSON.stringify(TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"][x]));
//  }

var rowData = TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"];
var backgroundColors = rowData.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
  if ("values" in r) {
    r.values.forEach((c, j) => {
      if ("effectiveFormat" in c) {
        ar.push({rowNumber: i + 1, columnNumber: j + 1, backgroundColor: c.effectiveFormat.backgroundColor});
      }
    });
  }
  return ar;
}, []);
console.log(backgroundColors)
```

#### Result:

When above script is used, the following result is retrieved.

```
[
  {"rowNumber":1,"columnNumber":1,"backgroundColor":{"blue":1,"red":1,"green":1}},
  ,
  ,
  ,
]
```

- In this case, `rowNumber` and `columnNumber` are the coordinate of cell.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

## Answer for question 2:

- You want to retrieve the background colors of `effectiveFormat` from a sheet and want to use the retrieved values as the background colors of `userEnteredFormat` for the batchUpdate.

  - You want to use the retrieved values for `colorrows` in the following script.

    ```
      var spreadsheetId = "1eAq-RbtrCSMRPZ0p7XIpG3vd29yL-3SQ3D3JGyiUhKg";
      var result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
        requests: [{
          updateCells: {
            rows: colorrows,
            fields: 'userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor',
            start: {
              sheetId: 1616717220,
              rowIndex: 0,
              columnIndex: 0
            }
          }
        }]
      }, spreadsheetId)
    ```

#### Sample script:

In this case, it is required to change the property name from `effectiveFormat` to `userEnteredFormat`.

```
var TestArray = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get("1pcIKNUFmkk0d-UGg1sXl5xbsJC2WhocIHpM3et-CMgo", {
  ranges:"TestBackgroundSheet!A1:AD39",
  fields:"sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveFormat.backgroundColor))))"
});

//  for (var x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
//    Logger.log(x + JSON.stringify(TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"][x]));
//  }

var rowData = TestArray["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"];
var colorrows = rowData.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
  var temp = [];
  if ("values" in r) {
    r.values.forEach((c, j) => {
      temp.push("effectiveFormat" in c ? {userEnteredFormat: {backgroundColor: c.effectiveFormat.backgroundColor}} : {});
    });
  }
  ar.push({values: temp});
  return ar;
}, []);
```

- In this case, `colorrows` can be used for above script of the batchUpdate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You code is far more advanced than I am able to do and the output is both clear and straight forward. If i'm not mistaken, this output isn't in the format required to for BatchUpdate. Does this need to be mapped again to define it in terms of  `{userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={red=1.0,blue=1.0,green=1.0}}}.` Does this get mapped with an index of `rowNumber` and `columnNumber`? Did you have a different intention as to how to use your current formatting. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @LANCE Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your question, I understood you wanted to remove `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`. Is my understanding correct? Because I cannot understand about `this output isn't in the format required to for BatchUpdate. Does this need to be mapped again to define it in terms of {userEnteredFormat={backgroundColor={red=1.0,blue=1.0,green=1.0}}}.`. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your expected output. My sample script is the sample values retrieved by removing the error. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I apologize for the lack of clarity. You are correct my question was trying to deal with the `SyntaxError: Unexpected Token`. Ultimately I want to the take the backgroundColors array and Batchupdate it back to another sheet. I have edited my original question under Edit #1. I've included my full piece of code that incorporates your fixes. I've also included what I believe are the expected formats. Please let me know if I can clarify things any further.

Comment: @LANCE Thank you for replying. I'm surprising that your question was changed. In your question, your 1st question was resolved. I understood that you added 2nd question. About your 2nd question, I added one more answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I sincerely apologize for the change in question. Because of lack of familiarity with the problem I didn't realize I was asking the wrong question. Your code works beautifully. I'm going to do some reading to understand this code completely. Thank you.